# Concatenating Objective-C NSStrings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I'm a total newbie at Objective-C, so bear with me. This is how I'm concatenating my URL:

```
id url      = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blahblah.com/gradient.jpg"];
id image    = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
id tiff     = [image TIFFRepresentation];

NSString *docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:  @"Desktop"];
NSString *fileToWrite = @"/test.tiff";
NSString *fullPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingString:fileToWrite];

[tiff writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
```

It works, but it seems sloppy. Is this the ideal way of doing concatenating NSStrings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringByAppendingString:` or `stringWithFormat:` pretty much is the way.

Comment: What if I wanted to write [tiff writeToFile...] with one line, and not using any variables within? I was trying to do that but wasn't very successful.

Comment: [tiff writeToFile:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:  @"Desktop"]; stringByAppendingString:@"/test.tiff"] atomically:YES];

Comment: ssteinberg, absolutely agree! But I was just wondering how it would actually be accomplished. Better to know than not to know :P

Comment: And just another question: Is concatenating slower than doing it by one line?

Comment: Nope. You are concatenating either way. Unless you need to do it huge amount of times per second, don't worry until your profiler says otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You can append multiple path components at once.  E.g.:

```
NSString* fullPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop/test.tiff"];
```

You can also specify the entire path in a single string:

```
NSString* fullPath = [@"~/Desktop/test.tiff" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [NSMutableString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

A common convention is to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` however it does not perform path appending (stringByAppendingPathComponent).